# Printing the Number of Different Letters in a String and Printing the Number of times that the Most Frequent Letter Appears

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I really need help for a school project. Have to write a program that:

```
1: Prints the number of different letters in a string.

2: Prints the number of vowels in a string.

3: Prints the number of uppercase letters in a string.

4: Prints the number of times that the most frequent letter appears in a string.

5: Prints the longest word in the string.
```

Currently I have numbers 2, 3, and 5 completed. I am really stumped on 1 and 4. I have tried google searching and looking on this and other programming websites.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class Practice_2 here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Practice_2
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Practice_2
     */
    public Practice_2()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        x = 0;
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public int sampleMethod(int y)
    {
        // put your code here
        return x + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = scan.nextLine();
        String[] sen = sentence.split("\\s");
        int numVowels = 0;
        int numUpper = 0;
        int [] alphaarray = new int[26];
        int longest = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sen.length; i ++)
        {
            char c = sen[i].charAt(sen[i].length()-1);
            if(sen[i].length() > sen[longest].length())
            {
                longest = i;
            }
            if(c == ',' && sen[i].length()-1 > sen[longest].length())
            {
                longest = i;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = sentence.charAt(i);
            if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U')
            {
                numVowels++;
            }
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            {
                numUpper++;
            }
            if (c == 'a') alphaarray[0]++;
            if (c == 'b') alphaarray[1]++;
        }



        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(numVowels);
        System.out.println(numUpper);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(sen[longest]);
    }

}
```

I really need to get this project finished. I am working on this in Java and using the program BlueJ to do this.

Clarifications:

- Program number 1 is supposed to print a number between 1 and 26 telling how many different letters there are.
- I would really like not to change any code that I already have because it works, as is.
- I only need help on numbers 1 and 4.
- Where it says "(New line)" is where an enter should be.
- Where it says "(Empty)" is where an answer should be.
- I know that there is a System.out.println at the end of the code that has (" "). That is where the variables for the answers to number 1 and 4 would go.
- The sentence can be up to 1024 letters long.
- I am aware that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786799/need-to-find-the-character-most-frequent-in-a-string-and-return-the-number-of-ti) post exists but when I tried to use it, I couldn't get it to work.
- I also know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945137/printing-out-the-letter-appears-the-most) post also exists but it is written in C and I need it in Java.

A sample input is:

```
The quick Brown fox, named Roxanne, jumped over Bruno, the lazy dog.
```

The output for this is:
(Empty)
19 (New line)
3 (New line)
(Empty)
Roxanne

I need it to be this:

25 (New line)
19 (New line)
3 (New line)
6 (New line)
Roxanne

This has to be done with loops and inside the `main(String[] args)` method.

I know it is late at night when I post this but any help is appreciated as this needs to be completed by 2:15 on Sunday.

Sincerely,
MrNoName

Comment: What code for #1 and #4 have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, for advice on asking homework questions, please consult this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4851565

Comment: @entpnerd I have tried this for number 1:
static final int MAX_CHAR = 1024; 
  
    static void getOccuringChar(String str) 
    { 
        // Create an array of size 256 i.e. ASCII_SIZE 
         int count[] = new int[MAX_CHAR]; 
  
        int len = str.length(); 
  
        // Initialize count array index 
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;

Comment: Since you are stuck with problem 1 and 4, let's focus on them. I suggest you have separate programs for each problem (Then may be combine them later). What did you try for Problem 1? I think you can start with this: `for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {char c = sentence.charAt(i);}`

Comment: Additionally, @MrNoName what data structures have you learned about so far that might help? If you haven't yet learned about any data structures, is there any clever indexing for arrays that you might do that can help you out?

Comment: @entpnerd
 // Create an array of given String size 
        char ch[] = new char[str.length()]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            ch[i] = str.charAt(i); 
            int find = 0; 
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
  
                // If any matches found 
                if (str.charAt(i) == ch[j])  
                    find++;                 
            } 
            if (find == 1)  
                System.out.println(count[str.charAt(i)]);             
        } 
    }
This prints all of the times each letter appears.

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda
What I have tried for number 1 is in a previous comment made by me.

Comment: @entpnerd
I am not familiar with data structures as I have just recently started coding. I do not know much about indexing either.

Comment: Can you think of a way that you might be able to use a second array to help you? How many letters is it possible to have in your problem? wink, wink...

Comment: Hint: For #1, you can have a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)` and you can use a data structure `Set` (`java.util.Set`) to keep the letters you come across. Then at the end, you can get the size of `Set`.

Comment: It is possible to have up to 1024 letters in the string and I could possibly use an array to store the letters in one variable

Comment: If you are not allowed to use such data structures or if you prefer not to use them, then you have to use an array for this.

Comment: There are code examples of all the listed items in StackOverflow.

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda I will likely continue to use arrays.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! I have learned a lot tonight and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For number one, you could make a 'checklist' in an array:

```
String sentencel=sentence.toLowerCase();
char[] letters;
letters=new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int numDiffLetters=0;
for(int i=0; i<sentencel.length(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<letters.length; j++){
        if(sentencel.charAt(i)==letters[j]){
            letters[j]='0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++){
    if(letters[i]=='0'){
        numDiffLetters++;
    }
}
```

And then print `numDiffLetters`.
For number four, you can find how much times each number appears and then find the highest number(you will need `sentencel` from number 1):

```
char[] letterarray;
letterarray=new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int[] letterTimes;
letterTimes=new int[26];
int numMostLetter=0;
for(int i=0; i<sentencel.length(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<letterarray.length; j++){
        if(sentencel.charAt(i)==letterarray[j]){
            letterTimes[j]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Arrays.sort(letterTimes);
numMostLetter=letterTimes[letterTimes.length-1];
```

And then print `numMostLetter`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I put that into the program and it worked! I really appreciate the help! I was going to try using an array that stores all of the times that each letter shows up but it printed out the wrong thing and was researching when I saw this! I am going to continue to look into it to see if my way would've worked. Once again, thanks for the help!!